# Returning a list from a function that stops on the word "bye" and depending on its position

Tags: python

So this is the question: Write a function called beginning that takes a list as input and contains a while loop that only stops once the element of the list is the string ‘bye’. What is returned is a list that contains up to the first 10 strings, regardless of where the loop stops. (i.e., if it stops on the 32nd element, the first 10 are returned. If “bye” is the 5th element, the first 4 are returned.)

I have the part where it stops if it gets to 'bye' but i don't know how to finish the last part.

```
def beginning(x):
    n = 0
    lst = []
    while "bye" not in x[n]:
        lst.append(x[n])
        n = n + 1
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a counter in your loop. Use it to add an extra condition:

```
def beginning(x):
    n = 0
    lst = []
    while "bye" not in x[n] and n < 10:
        lst.append(x[n])
        n = n + 1
    return lst
```

If `lst` reachs length 10, you do not need to check further, you already have your 10 elements, so you can stop iterating.

#### EDIT after comments

As pointed out in the comments, if you are looking for an exact match, this code does not work. The while loop condition instead should be:

```
while "bye" != x[n] and n < 10:
```

`"bye" not in x[n]` returns `False` if the string `x[n]` contains "bye", so "Goodbye" will also stop the iteration.

Comment: Doesn't work. `x = ["Goodbyes" , "are" , "not" , "forever" ]` Notice that `"bye" not in x[0]` will return false. And your function will return the empty list.

Comment: @MFisherKDX that should be expected behaviour I think. 'bye' is in the string (that is the code the OP wrote), so in that case the length should be 0. But I will add a solution for exact matches.

Comment: *only stops once the element of the list is the string ‘bye’* -> seems to me that the string must be exactly "bye"

Answer (score 1):

What should happen if "bye" is not on the list? Should it return 10 elements too? If that's the case then here:

```
def beginning(lis):
    ls = []
    counter = 1
    for st in lis:
        if (st != "bye") and (counter <=10):
            ls.append(st)
        else:
            return ls
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this problem:

```
def beginning(x):
    ls = []
    idx = 0
    while idx<10:
        if x[idx]=="bye":
            break
        ls.append(x[idx])
        idx+=1
    return ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple but lengthy solution

```
def beginning(lst):
    ten=10
    a=0
    new_list=[]
    while a<len(lst) and lst[a]!='bye':
        new_list.append(lst[a])
        a+=1
    if len(new_list)>10 or len(new_list)==10:
        return new_list[:10]
    else:
        return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def beginning(list1):
    sub_list = []
    final_list = []
    if len(list1) > 10:
        sub_list = list1[:10]
        count = 0
    while (count<len(sub_list)) and (sub_list[count] != "bye"):
        final_list.append(sub_list[count])
        count = count + 1
    return final_list
```

this way i tried , is by using the most basic functions ,if you just read once you will get it and remember the way too ! since i am a novice learner this is the only way i know !
#check_this_out!

Comment: Please add more details about how this solution works and why it is a good solution https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: this way i tried , is by using the most basic functions ,if you just read once you will get it and remember the way too ! since i am a novice learner this is the only way i know

Answer (score 0):

```
def beginning(lst):
    new_list = []
    start = 0
    while start < 10 and lst[start] != 'bye':
        new_list.append(lst[start])
        start += 1
        
    return new_list

list1 = ["Hello", "There", "bye", "Hi", "K", "EHEH", "Edkf"]
print(beginning(list1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the index of the first 'bye' and return the list up to that point, or up to 10, whichever is first.

```
def beginning(x):
    return x[:min(x.index('bye'),9)]
```

Comment: Need to handle ValueError if 'bye' is not in the list.

Comment: @MFisherKDX that doesn't seem to be a requirement of his ask.

Comment: Umm ... so I guess it's okay then to crash if the list doesn't contain "bye".

Comment: @MFisherKDX According to him it will always contain that word.  Who is to say he doesn't check that prior to sending it to the function?  I'm not telling him where to handle errors in his code, I'm showing one of the many approaches he can use to solve his problem.  If he likes the approach, he can throw in a line of code to handle the edge case.

Comment: Nowhere in the OPs problem statement does it say the list will necessarily contain the word "bye". Downvoting. Otherwise, I honestly like your solution the best. No need for an explicit loop.